# positioning the text in the center of li tag

Tags: css

I have created three blocks using the html code as shown below. The "a" tag has the min-height css property because of which it will be displayed as block. I am not able to place the text inside the span tag in the center of "`li`" tag. Although each text inside the  tag is of different length, I want to display them in the center.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav-tabs">
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Data</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Charts</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Reports</span>
            </a>
          </li>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
}

.col-md-4 {
    width: 33%;
}
.nav-block {
    background-color: #FFA500;
    display: block;
    min-height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.container .nav-block .header {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 21%;
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below css.

```
  .nav-block {
        background-color: #FFA500;
        display: block;
        min-height: 70px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center; /*New Edit*/
    }


    .container .nav-block .header {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*left: 20%; - Remove*/
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        top: 21%;
    }
```

Comment: This helped. Could you please explain why we added the text-align in both blocks above and also why did we remove the left: 20% in the second block?

Answer (score 1):

just changed the css to center the texts, check in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdztn/1/)

```
.nav-block {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  display: block;
  min-height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .nav-block .header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 21%;
}
```

Comment: I think he want to center the anchor inside `li` item instead.

Comment: Not really, you can use inspector tools to check it

Comment: I wanted the text inside the span to be placed center relative to li element

Comment: Hmm... I can't understand what you're asking for. As far as I understood, the span is centered relative to the anchor which has the same width as the li. Sorry it didn't help =(

Comment: Yes. if the span is centered to the anchor it will be implicitly aligned center to the li element

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `text-align:center;` on the `li{}`

And delete the `position:relative;` on `.container .nav-block .header {`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2pfK9/)**

With editting my sugestions you have a shorter css, because you can delete the unaccecary things. Like here.

```
.container .nav-block .header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2pfK9/1/)** (same as the other but less css)

Answer (score 0):

just add     `text-align:center;` to .nav-tabs or .nav-block

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your `<ul>` tag.

I hope this is what you want ->

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Psbq/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="tabs" class="nav-tabs">
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Data</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Charts</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 nav-list">
            <a href="#" class="nav-block">
              <span class="header">Reports</span>
            </a>
          </li>

        <!--closing the ul tag-->

        </ul> 
      </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container ul {
list-style: none outside none;
}

li {
 display: list-item;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33%;
}
.nav-block {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  display: block;
  min-height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center; /*aligning the text center*/
  line-height:60px; /*this gives vertical alignment to your element*/
}

.container .nav-block .header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0; /*removed the defined 20% to center you text inside anchor <a> tags*/
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 21%;
}
```